# PrimeFaces Schedule: Custom Header button

Tags: jsf, primefaces, header

My friends and me have a web-application. For the GUI we have to use PrimeFaces. At one point we have to implement calendar and we choose to use the PrimeFaces schedule. But here we got a problem. The "month" and "week" header buttons are fine, but for the "day" we need to call another page. So now to the question. Is there a way to make the "day" custom button? I tried with the "rightHeaderTemplate" attribute, but i don't know how to address something there. The PrimeFaces-docs weren't helpful either...

Here is the xhtml part:

```
<h:panelGrid columnClasses="value" >
        <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{calenderView.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" 
                    locale="de" rightHeaderTemplate="month, agendaWeek, customButtonHere">

                <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{calenderView.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails1" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
                <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{calenderView.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails1" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
                <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{calenderView.onEventMove}"  />
                <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{calenderView.onEventResize}"  />

         </p:schedule>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The "customButtonHere" is the place we would like to have our own type of button. Can we make that in xhtml?

for the most part we just copied the code form the official site:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should ask the professor what 'client-side html' is and how you can interact with it in javascript/jquery

Comment: `p:schedule` uses fullcalendar, so maybe you can play with this https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/customButtons/?

Comment: Thanks @OuerghiYassine !! the website helps alot! :)

Comment: @OuerghiYassine: Is PF already on fullCalendar 2.4?

Comment: @Kukeltje according to primefaces s repo, they're on FullCalendar v2.9.1

Comment: Oh, cool, I had the impression they were on 2.2... Thanks for the good suggestion.